# Briggs alternator identification

Tags: alternator, part-identification, lawnmower, briggs-stratton

[image][image]
These are pics of the alternator, yes I have looked at the Briggs guide, the most similar one I’ve found is the 397880 but this does not have the capacitors on it. I’ve spent hours looking so maybe someone more experienced could help, I’d very much appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is that "Briggs" as in "Briggs and Stratton"?

Comment: Yes sir, at least they were in a box with other Briggs and Stratton part I could Identify.

Comment: Where did you get these parts? If they are "old stock" or from a friend's garage then they may not match the current parts as supplied...

Comment: They were part of a large selection in boxes that my old shop teacher gave me, they seem newer plastic than some very old stuff in that box which I've found id's for.

Comment: https://www.briggsandstratton.com/content/dam/briggsandstratton/na/en_us/Files/FAQs/alternator_id.pdf          This sheet covers items since the 70's so it may just not be listed under common parts